# Sort field in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I have table about 20-25 million records, I  have to put in another table based on some condition and also sorted. Example

```
Create table X AS
select * from Y 
where item <> 'ABC'
Order By id;
```

I know that Order by Uses single reducer to guarantee total order in output. 
I need optimize way to do sorting for above query.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the problem?

Comment: need the solution for sorting large amount of data.

Comment: And your current query does not work for you because ...?

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets. This is *especially* true in parallel databases where the data is spread among multiple processors.

That said, Hive does support clustered indexes (which essentially define partitions) and sorting within the partitions. The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL) is quite specific, though, that this is *not* supported with `CREATE TABLE AS`:

> CTAS has these restrictions:
>
> - The target table cannot be a partitioned table.

You could do what you want by exporting the data and re-importing it.

However, I would suggest that you figure out what you really need without requiring the data to be ordered *within* the database.